# What do you call a provider who works on a offshore outsourced project?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, titles

I just started working online and I want to know the proper term (noun) for that kind of worker. I work for a foreign company from home. They **pay me monthly** as a full time employee and **we have a long term agreement** like a regular day job. So **I can't call it freelance**. What is the term that would define what I am doing?

Another term I am also confused with: "**outsourcing/outsource**." According to the dictionary it means:

```
To delegate (a task, function, or responsibility) to an independent provider
```

So in my point of view the **company I am working for is "outsourcing."** So what do you call the term that I am doing? Is there any fancy word for the worker?

Comment: First, what is your tax jurisdiction?  If you're in the US (and likely there's something similar in most European countries) there is a significant difference between being a "regular employee" vs a "contractor", and it's not clear which you are.  Second, there are two relationships here, between you and your employer, and between your employer and the company they "outsource" for.  These probably need to be describes separately and somewhat independently (depending on now "legal" your "terminology" needs to be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it *remote work.*

See [this,](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote) for example.

So you can say *I work remotely, I'm a remote worker,* etc. To specify additional information, you probably need to just describe it further: *I work remotely for a foreign company.*

Since there are various additional possibilities regarding arrangements and status, you would need to add words like *permanent, full-time, permanent employee, from home, from (name of city, country, region),* etc.

If you are not considered an employee of the company, by the company or by laws governing them or you, then you are a contractor. I doubt that there is a more specific word that means *oursourced supplier of services.*

Comment: I find the term offshore employee explanatory

Comment: If it's useful to you, then it's useful! But be aware: when I hear *offshore,* its most common meaning comes into my mind. For example, when I first read the title to your post, I thought of someone working on an oil rig in an ocean, some distance from the shore. I can't say how many others would think in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You are the company's "Outsource" (Outside Resource), "Virtual Assistant," or "Remote Worker."

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.